# The Cantor set and integrability of $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Let $\chi_C$ be the characteristic function of the standard Cantor set fully contained in the interval $[0,1]$. The problem is to resolve if $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0^{+}} \int_{\varepsilon}^1\frac{\chi_C}{x}dx$:

a) doesn't exist

b) is equal to $+\infty$.

c) exists.

Note: If there is computed $\int_{\varepsilon}^1\frac{\chi_C}{x}dx$ for $\varepsilon>0$, then please use [R-integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f$ is bounded on $[\epsilon,1]$, so you just need to show that the integral of a bounded function which vanishes outside the Cantor set is zero. Use the fact that the Cantor set is covered by a finite union of closed intervals of arbitrarily small measure.

Comment: So for any $\varepsilon > 0 $ we have: $I(\varepsilon)=\int_{\varepsilon}^1\frac{\chi_C}{x}dx$, and: $$0\leqslant I(\varepsilon) \leqslant \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int\limits_C\chi_C dx=0$$
What implies that: $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0^{+}}I(\varepsilon)=0$ and option c) as suitable here.

Comment: Yep, that's right!

Answer (score 5):

The standard Cantor set has Lebesgue measure zero, so you just have to integrate $0$.

Comment: Note that $f(x)$ is not bounded. I don't cancel your answer, but I don't feel convinced.

Comment: What integral do you use? As you have noted, $f$ is not Riemann integrable, so I assumed that you use the Lebesgue integral. And if it is the case, the integral is not dependent on changes of the integrated function on a null set.

Comment: Yes, but I also mentioned using improper integral.There is no Lebesgue integrating here.

Comment: So what integral do you use?

Comment: It's simple $$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0^{+}} \int_{\varepsilon}^1f(x)dx$$

Comment: But what integral? Riemann? Newton? Else?

Comment: If you consider $\int_{\varepsilon}^1f(x)dx$, where $\varepsilon>0$, then use R-integrating.

Comment: Then the question is more complicated. I would suggest you to edit the question such that it is clear that you consider the indefinite Riemann integral.

Comment: It's done, and unambiguously exposed.

Comment: $f$ is bounded on $[\epsilon, 1]$, so you just need to show that the integral of a bounded function which vanishes outside the Cantor set is zero. Simply use the fact that the Cantor set is covered by a finite union of closed intervals of arbitrarily small measure. (ETA finite, which is important because you're using the Riemann integral.)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I am thinking about this same,are you studying at faculty of mathematics?

Comment: erm, yes? That's a random question to ask...

Comment: (I assume you meant facility)

Comment: @user124187 You have written: "...Then the question is more complicated...", what do you think about Dustan's hint?

Comment: Dustan's hint is very helpful. Following the hint, you are able to show that the integral is still $0$. But it is not as trivial as in the case of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I can post your hint as an answer and I think I'll mark it.

Comment: sure, I'll do that.